# Differential equation for the distance travelled

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A motorboat and its load weigh 2150N. Assuming the propeller force is constant and equal to 110 newtons and water resistance is equal numerically to 6.7V Newton where V is the velocity at any instant in m/s, and the boat starts from rest determine the speed and the distance traveled at the end of 10 seconds.

---I managed to solve for the speed which I found to be v=4.32m/s, I used the equation ma = T-kv using FBD, then solved it using linear DE. Now I'm having difficulty on how can I get the distance travelled, what equation should I work on for the distance?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So you used $\dot v=a$. Now use $\dot x=v$.

Comment: While finding v, you must have gotten v as a function of t. Now integrate that and use x(0)=0.

Comment: As an aside:  because $ \ 10 \ $ seconds is fairly small compared to the "characteristic time" $ \ \frac{m}{k} \ \approx \ \frac{219.2}{6.7} \ = \ 32.7 \ $ seconds, the distance covered is pretty well estimated by taking the average velocity times $ \ 10 \ $ seconds, or $ \ 21.6 \ $ meters.  The exact answer from the integration of $ \ v(t) \ $ is slightly larger.  (This is because the "net thrust" of the propellor against the drag from the water has only been reduced about 26 percent after 10 seconds.)